# c++ template return type depending on template arguments?

Tags: c++, templates, generic-programming

I have implemented my own SI Unit class. When using arithmetic operations the resulting SI Unit can change. E.g: ( meter / second ) / meter = 1 / second.

Ok now I have also created a simple 3D Vector class. This vector shall be generic and also usable with my SI Unit class. So I implemented a simple division operator.
See the following code:

```
// Determine result type of Lhs / Rhs:
template < class Lhs, class Rhs >
    struct TV3TypeV3Div { typedef BOOST_TYPEOF( Lhs( ) / Rhs( ) ) type; };

// Vector / Vector:
template < class Lhs, class Rhs >
RobotTools::DataTypes::TV3Type< typename TV3TypeV3Div< Lhs, Rhs >::type > operator/( const RobotTools::DataTypes::TV3Type< Lhs >& lhs,
                                                                                     const RobotTools::DataTypes::TV3Type< Rhs >& rhs )
{
    // do something useful
    return RobotTools::DataTypes::TV3Type< typename TV3TypeV3Div< Lhs, Rhs >::type >( 0, 0, 0 );
}

// Vector / Vector
RobotTools::DataTypes::TV3Type< Tools::DataTypes::Length > vl;
vl / vl;  // Ok this works
```

During compile time the right return type will be determined by using the TV3TypeV3Div struct. This works.

Now I want to extend the operators. I want also calculate vectors with scalar types. So I wrote this operator:

```
// Vector / Scalar
template < class Lhs, class Rhs >
RobotTools::DataTypes::TV3Type< typename TV3TypeV3Div< Lhs, Rhs >::type > operator/( const RobotTools::DataTypes::TV3Type< Lhs >& lhs,
                                                                                     const Rhs& rhs )
{
    // do something useful
    return RobotTools::DataTypes::TV3Type< typename TV3TypeV3Div< Lhs, Tools::DataTypes::Length >::type >( 0, 0, 0 );
}

// Vector / Scalar
RobotTools::DataTypes::TV3Type< Tools::DataTypes::Length > vl;
Tools::DataTypes::Length sl;
vl / sl;  // Ok nice it works too
```

So far so good. The problem is when I define the second operator (Vector/Scalar) this operator is so generic that the compiler wants to use it also for Vector/Vector division.
But it fails because Lhs( ) / Rhs( ) with:

Lhs=Tools::DataTypes::Length and Rhs=RobotTools::DataTypes::TV3Type

is not defined. This is correct and I understand the given error. What I do not understand is that the compiler does NOT use the Vector/Vector operator.

- Is there any possibility to give the compiler a hint which operator to use ?
- Is there any possibility to rewrite the operators to fullfill my requirement ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler does not want to use the Vector/Scalar operator for Vector/Vector division. It just wants to make check if there's a match.

If you declare (but not define) a completely generic division operator

```
template <typename Lhs, typename Rhs>
struct InvalidDivision {};
template <typename Lhs, typename Rhs>
InvalidDivision<Lhs, Rhs> 
operator/(const Lhs& lhs, const Rhs& rhs); // do not define
```

then your code should compile and link. The Vector/Scalar overload will be considered and rejected because Vector/Vector is a better match.

The downside of it is if you do divide things that do not have division defined for them, the compiler will complain about `InvalidDivision<something,other>` instead of giving its usual error.

Perhaps this could be improved by using SFINAE or some other advanced magic.

**Update: a more detailed explanation**

What is going on in the original version of the code?

We are trying to invoke a division operator for a user-defined type. There are two functions named `operator/` and the compiler considers both and tries to find out which one is a better match.

First consider the Vector/Vector `operator/`. The compiler deduces that both `Lhs` and `Rhs` template parameters are `Length` (I omit namespaces for brevity). It then substitutes them into parameters of `TV3TypeV3Div`, computes the insides of `TV3TypeV3Div`, determines that `TV3TypeV3Div<Lhs,Rhs>::type` is also `Length`, and finally computes the return type of `operator/` which is `TV3Type<Length>`.

Now consider the Vector/Scalar `operator/`. The compiler deduces that `Lhs` is `Length`, but `Rhs` is `TV3Type<Length>`. It then substitutes these types into parameters of `TV3TypeV3Div`, and tries to compute the insides of `TV3TypeV3Div`. Here's where things break up: there/s no `operator/` that would accept `Length` and `TV3Type<Length>`. So it is impossible to compute `TV3TypeV3Div<Lhs,Rhs>::type`. The compiler outputs an error.

Now consider what happens when the generic `operator/` is declared. Now there *is* an `operator/` that would accept `Length` and `TV3Type<Length>`! (Or any other pair of arguments, for that matter). So the compiler happily computes `TV3TypeV3Div<Lhs,Rhs>::type` and then the return type of Vector/Scalar `operator/`. So now it is possible to consider both Vector/Vector and Vector/Scalar `operator/` overloads.

The compiler now also sees and considers the generic `operator/` for the overload resolution. All three overloads produce a match. But the Vector/Vector overload wins, because it is more specialized then either Vector/Scalar or generic `operator/`, and is therefore a better match.

**Update 2**

It should be possible to do this:

```
namespace Detail
{
    template <typename Lhs, typename Rhs>
        struct DoNotUse {};
    template <typename Lhs, typename Rhs>
        DoNotUse<Lhs, Rhs> operator/(const Lhs& lhs, const Rhs& rhs);
    template < class Lhs, class Rhs >
        struct TV3TypeV3Div { typedef BOOST_TYPEOF( Lhs( ) / Rhs( ) ) type; };
}
using Detail::TV3TypeV3Div;
```

This should nicely hide the generic operator/ from everyone but `TV3TypeV3Div`.

Comment: I am confused ! This really works. I spent the whole day for this simple solution :) Can you please explain it a little bit more. I do not see the magic.

Comment: I have added some explanation.

Comment: Thanks n.m. for the great explanation. In the meantime I tried your approach within my original project. But it fails at multiple places with the "InvalidDivision..." error code. I think it will be not so easy to update the whole project. So maybe I need some SFINAE magic maybe by using boost ? Any ideas ?

Comment: Try putting `TV3TypeV3Div` and `InvalidDivision` and `InvalidDivision operator/` in `namespace Detail`, and then say `using Detail::TV3TypeV3Div`. This should hide the generic operator/ from everyone.

Comment: Yes this does finally solve my problem. Simple and elegant ! Tanks a lot !